# Remove all text except a certain string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I'm extracting case numbers from a wall of text. How do I filter out all the useless text using the replace function in Notepad++ with the help of RegEx? The parts I want to keep are made up of letters, digits, and a hyphen (SPP-1803-2045227).

I would like to turn this...

```
(SPP-1803-2045227)Useless text goes here. 2019-05-18 *
(SPP-1915-1802667)More useless text. 2019-01-14 *
(SPP-1904-1012523)And some more. 2019-02-03 *
```

...into this:

```
SPP-1803-2045227
SPP-1915-1802667
SPP-1904-1012523
```

I've been playing around with RegEx and also found something in another thread on here before, which wasn't the solution but came very close. Unfortunately I can't find it anymore. It looked something like this:

```
^(?!S\w+).*\r?\n?
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this.

find: `.*\((\w{3}-\d{4}-\d{7})\).*`

replace with: `\1`

The above Regular Expression matches the whole line with your letters and digits between an extra pair of parentheses.
When you replace with `\1` you keep only the match between parentheses.

Remember to select Regular Expression Search mode.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm! I will try to figure out what each part does exactly by reading about it online. Thank you very much.